# CriticalSection Crash while calling GetPrinterDataFromPort

Tags: c++, winapi, printing, crash, windbg

This is a crash I am trying to analyze for so many days. Can anyone please help me analyzing the issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

We have customized the Language Monitor for our printer. There is a thread that polls the printer for it's status for every minute. The function GetPrinterDataFromPort from DDK gets the printer status data. The crash originates from here.

```
bResult = g_stMonitor.pfnGetPrinterDataFromPort
                    (  m_hPort,
                       dwIOCTLUSB,
                       NULL,
                       (LPWSTR) byCmdBuf,   (DWORD)sizeof byCmdBuf,
                       (LPWSTR) (&vRsp[0]), (DWORD)vRsp.size(),
                       &dwLen
                       );
```

The g_stMonitor->pfnGetPrinterDataFromPort is initialized to DDKs Port Monitor structure as below. The g_stMonitor and it's function pointers are perfectly valid before the call.

```
g_stMonitor->pfnGetPrinterDataFromPort = pDDKMon->pfnGetPrinterDataFromPort;
```

Here is the call stack of the crashing thread: (Modified Printer DLL name and function names)

```
0:006> kbM
# ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 00d7f68c 7c901046 00365db0 723f2894 00365db0 ntdll!RtlpWaitForCriticalSection+0x8c
01 00d7f694 723f2894 00365db0 00d7f6d8 00365d68 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x46
02 00d7f6b0 723f2acb 00d7fbcc 00dee0b0 00000000 usbmon!CBasePort::open+0x1a
03 00d7f6dc 723f1c07 0022003c 00000000 00d7f950 usbmon!CBasePort::getPrinterDataFromPort+0x55
04 00d7f700 00aaac27 007f67c0 0022003c 00000000 usbmon!DynaMon_GetPrinterDataFromPort+0x31
05 00d7f968 00aadf64 00000000 00000014 00000100 Printer_DLL!PrintPrimitives::CPortMon::getPrinterDataFromPort_Base+0x267
06 00d7fb9c 00b61200 00000000 00000014 00000100 Printer_DLL!PrintPrimitives::CPortMon::GetPrinterDataFromPort+0xd4
07 00d7fbf0 00b402e6 00d7fd58 00d7fc10 122de300 Printer_DLL!PrintPrimitives::CMyPrinter::refreshStatus_+0x60
08 00d7fc88 00b43834 00d7fd58 00000000 122de194 Printer_DLL!PrintPrimitives::CMyVariant::refreshStatus_+0x86
09 00d7fe1c 00b36424 00000000 00000000 00000000 Printer_DLL!PrintPrimitives::CMyVariant::pollPlusWin32_+0xc4
0a 00d7fe30 00b5bfeb 00000000 00000000 00a9c3d8 Printer_DLL!PrintPrimitives::CMyVariant::poll_+0x14
0b 00d7fe3c 00a9c3d8 122de09c 7c91003d 00c99668 Printer_DLL!PrintPrimitives::CMyPrinter::refreshStatus_+0xb
0c 00d7ff14 00a9c839 122de0f8 7c911432 00c989f8 Printer_DLL!OSBase::CThread::threadMain+0x3a8
0d 00d7ff70 00ae9836 00c99668 122de020 7c91003d Printer_DLL!OSBase::CThread::threadEntryEx+0x49
0e 00d7ffa8 00ae98c0 7c911432 00d7ffec 7c80b713 Printer_DLL!_callthreadstartex+0x1b
0f 00d7ffb4 7c80b713 00c9c5d8 7c91003d 7c911432 Printer_DLL!_threadstartex+0x64
10 00d7ffec 00000000 00ae985c 00c9c5d8 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37
```

The call to g_stMonitor.pfnGetPrinterDataFromPort() is from the frame 05.

#### Start of Paramters to g_stMonitor.pfnGetPrinterDataFromPort

The values that are passed to pfnGetPrinterDataFromPort() are valid.

```
0:006> dd 00d7f700 
00d7f700  00d7f968 00aaac27 007f67c0 0022003c
00d7f710  00000000 00d7f950 00000008 00ddc058
00d7f720  00000008 00d7f74c 122de6e0 00000000
00d7f730  00dee0b0 00000000 00c90838 00ae7781
00d7f740  00d7f9fc 00000002 00000000 00000000
00d7f750  0022003c 00000002 00000000 00ae7781
00d7f760  00000068 00000002 00000000 00ae7781
00d7f770  00000000 00000002 00000000 00ae7781
```

m_hPort: 007f67c0

dwIOCTLUSB: 0022003c (which is IOCTL_USBPRINT_VENDOR_GET_COMMAND)

3rd parameter is NULL at 00d7f710

byCmdBuf: 00d7f950

```
0:006> db 00d7f950 
00d7f950  14 01 00 00 00 00 00 00-e0 e6 2d 12 90 fb d7 00  ..........-.....
```

14 01 00 is the get status command

(DWORD)sizeof byCmdBuf shows 8

&vRsp[0] is at 00ddc058

it's size is 8 at address 00d7f720

dwLen is at address 00d7f74c

#### END of Paramters to g_stMonitor.pfnGetPrinterDataFromPort

In the call stack above, the parameter passed to ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection is 00365db0. This is the address of CRITICAL_SECTION object.

```
0:006> dd 00365db0 
00365db0  00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000
```

This shows that the parameter passed is NULL. That means the CS is not initialized.

The !analyze -v shows the below result:

#### Start of !analyze -v

0:006> !analyze -v

---

- *
- Exception Analysis                                   *
- *

  ---

FAULTING_IP: 
ntdll!RtlpWaitForCriticalSection+8c
7c91b1fa ff4010          inc     dword ptr [eax+10h]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 7c91b1fa (ntdll!RtlpWaitForCriticalSection+0x0000008c)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000001
   Parameter[1]: 00000010
Attempt to write to address 00000010

PROCESS_NAME:  spoolsv.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000001

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  00000010

WRITE_ADDRESS:  00000010

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
spoolsv!main+b
010043cc 6a00            push    0

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  spoolsv.exe

CRITICAL_SECTION:  00365db0 -- (!cs -s 00365db0)

BLOCKING_THREAD:  000006bc

DERIVED_WAIT_CHAIN:

Dl Eid Cid     WaitType

---

6   6b8.a2c Critical Section       -->
   0   6b8.6bc File IO

WAIT_CHAIN_COMMAND:  ~6s;k;;~0s;k;;

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_WRITE

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_WRITE

FAULTING_THREAD:  00000000

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_WRITE_BlockedOn_FileIO

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 7c90d9bc to 7c90e4f4

STACK_TEXT:
0007fbd0 7c90d9bc 7c801879 0000006c 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
0007fbd4 7c801879 0000006c 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtReadFile+0xc
0007fc3c 77df346b 0000006c 0007fd08 00000216 kernel32!ReadFile+0x16c
0007fc68 77df32ff 0000006c 0007fd08 00000216 advapi32!ScGetPipeInput+0x2a
0007fcdc 77df3608 0000006c 0007fd08 00000216 advapi32!ScDispatcherLoop+0x3f
0007ff3c 010043cc 0100d508 01004729 00000001 advapi32!StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW+0xe3
0007ff44 01004729 00000001 00363e88 00362a90 spoolsv!main+0xb
0007ffc0 7c817067 0007fbc8 00000000 7ffd8000 spoolsv!mainCRTStartup+0x3b
0007fff0 00000000 0100461b 00000000 78746341 kernel32!BaseProcessStart+0x23

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  6

SYMBOL_NAME:  spoolsv!main+b

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: spoolsv

IMAGE_NAME:  spoolsv.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  48025ce1

STACK_COMMAND:  dt ntdll!LdrpLastDllInitializer BaseDllName ; dt ntdll!LdrpFailureData ; ~0s ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_WRITE_c0000005_spoolsv.exe!main

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_WRITE_BlockedOn_FileIO_spoolsv!main+b

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/spoolsv_exe/5_1_2600_5512/48025ce1/ntdll_dll/5_1_2600_5512/4802a12c/c0000005/0001b1fa.htm?Retriage=1

### Followup: MachineOwner

#### End of !analyze -v

The crash occurs after the Language monitor starts and when the g_stMonitor.pfnGetPrinterDataFromPort is called for the first time.

Here are the things I tried to fix.

1. I have observed that the LM code is calling UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevicesA call when the printer is installed in a device class other than printers. The poll is happening in parallel. So I have synchronized poll and Update driver call. Even after this the poll call failed.
2. I thought somehow the port is corrupted after the update driver call. So I moved the Update driver call before the port connection is established. This did not solve the issue. More over the UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevicesA hanged.

I am new to WinDDK. Can anyone help me on this crash?

Edits:

```
0:006> !cs 00365db0 00d7f6d8 00365d68
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x7c97b720
Critical section   = 0x003b0608 (+0x3B0608)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x7c97b740
Critical section   = 0x003c0608 (+0x3C0608)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x7c97b920
Critical section   = 0x003e0608 (+0x3E0608)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x00099168
Critical section   = 0x00380608 (+0x380608)

NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x0009e530
Critical section   = 0x007b0608 (+0x7B0608)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x0009e5d0
Critical section   = 0x007f0608 (+0x7F0608)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x0009e648
Critical section   = 0x00840608 (+0x840608)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a3a30
Critical section   = 0x00980608 (+0x980608)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a3bf8
Critical section   = 0x006f0608 (+0x6F0608)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a4738
Critical section   = 0x00710608 (+0x710608)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a4a30
Critical section   = 0x007124a8 (+0x7124A8)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7dd0
Critical section   = 0x00c90608 (+0xC90608)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x850
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7df8
Critical section   = 0x00c13328 Printer_DLL!lclcritsects+0x0)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7e20
Critical section   = 0x00c13340 Printer_DLL!lclcritsects+0x18)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7e48
Critical section   = 0x00c13358 Printer_DLL!lclcritsects+0x30)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7e70
Critical section   = 0x00c13370 Printer_DLL!lclcritsects+0x48)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7e98
Critical section   = 0x00c13388 Printer_DLL!lclcritsects+0x60)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7ec0
Critical section   = 0x00c133a0 Printer_DLL!lclcritsects+0x78)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7ee8
Critical section   = 0x00c133b8 Printer_DLL!lclcritsects+0x90)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7f10
Critical section   = 0x00c133d0 Printer_DLL!lclcritsects+0xA8)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7f38
Critical section   = 0x00c133e8 Printer_DLL!lclcritsects+0xC0)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7f60
Critical section   = 0x00c13400 Printer_DLL!lclcritsects+0xD8)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7f88
Critical section   = 0x00c13418 Printer_DLL!lclcritsects+0xF0)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7fb0
Critical section   = 0x00c13430 Printer_DLL!lclcritsects+0x108)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7fd8
Critical section   = 0x00c13448 Printer_DLL!lclcritsects+0x120)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a76c8
Critical section   = 0x00c13460 Printer_DLL!lclcritsects+0x138)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a76f0
Critical section   = 0x00c12490 Printer_DLL!mtx+0x0)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x218
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7718
Critical section   = 0x00c124a8 Printer_DLL!mtx+0x18)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7740
Critical section   = 0x00c124c0 Printer_DLL!mtx+0x30)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7768
Critical section   = 0x00c124d8 Printer_DLL!mtx+0x48)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7790
Critical section   = 0x00c93e28 (+0xC93E28)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7860
Critical section   = 0x00c94bcc (+0xC94BCC)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x21C
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a78b0
Critical section   = 0x00c121ec Printer_DLL!OSBase::g_ShutdownHandler+0x0)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a78d8
Critical section   = 0x00c96448 (+0xC96448)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7900
Critical section   = 0x00c122f4 Printer_DLL!USB80mm::g_evtLog+0x64)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7c80
Critical section   = 0x00c95210 (+0xC95210)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a7ca8
Critical section   = 0x00c99e14 (+0xC99E14)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a8118
Critical section   = 0x00c99f10 (+0xC99F10)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000a81c0
Critical section   = 0x00c9ba1c (+0xC9BA1C)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000aa898
Critical section   = 0x007f5c3c (+0x7F5C3C)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000aa758
Critical section   = 0x007f5cd4 (+0x7F5CD4)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000aa8c0
Critical section   = 0x007f5d6c (+0x7F5D6C)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000aa8e8
Critical section   = 0x007f5e04 (+0x7F5E04)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000aa910
Critical section   = 0x007f5e9c (+0x7F5E9C)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000aa938
Critical section   = 0x007f5f34 (+0x7F5F34)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000aa960
Critical section   = 0x007f5fcc (+0x7F5FCC)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000aa988
Critical section   = 0x007f6064 (+0x7F6064)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000aa9b0
Critical section   = 0x007f6104 (+0x7F6104)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x3E4
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000b3630
Critical section   = 0x007b1eb4 (+0x7B1EB4)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000b3658
Critical section   = 0x007b49d8 (+0x7B49D8)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000b3790
Critical section   = 0x007b1ef0 (+0x7B1EF0)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000b3d78
Critical section   = 0x007f68f4 (+0x7F68F4)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000b4088
Critical section   = 0x007f698c (+0x7F698C)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000b0d10
Critical section   = 0x007f6a24 (+0x7F6A24)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000b42d8
Critical section   = 0x007f6c48 (+0x7F6C48)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000b4300
Critical section   = 0x007f84c8 (+0x7F84C8)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000b4328
Critical section   = 0x007f9830 (+0x7F9830)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000c0488
Critical section   = 0x0036956c (+0x36956C)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000ad2f8
Critical section   = 0x00c97288 (+0xC97288)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000f9688
Critical section   = 0x00c963a8 (+0xC963A8)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000f99a8
Critical section   = 0x00c9bbf8 (+0xC9BBF8)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000f9ef8
Critical section   = 0x00c9263c (+0xC9263C)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000e8d50
Critical section   = 0x00c9267c (+0xC9267C)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000fa0
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x00104290
Critical section   = 0x00365db0 (+0x365DB0)
LOCKED
LockCount          = 0x1
OwningThread       = 0x00000000
RecursionCount     = 0x0
LockSemaphore      = 0xAA8
SpinCount          = 0x00000000

WARNING: critical section DebugInfo = 0x00000000 doesn't point back
to the DebugInfo found in the active critical sections list = 0x00104290.
The critical section was probably reused without calling DeleteCriticalSection.

Cannot read structure field value at 0x00000002, error 0
ntdll!RtlpStackTraceDataBase is NULL. Probably the stack traces are not enabled.
ntdll!RtlpStackTraceDataBase is NULL. Probably the stack traces are not enabled.
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x00110fc8
Critical section   = 0x00c966e8 (+0xC966E8)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x000e83f8
Critical section   = 0x007fc7cc (+0x7FC7CC)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
-----------------------------------------
DebugInfo          = 0x0009e028
Critical section   = 0x007fd1bc (+0x7FD1BC)
NOT LOCKED
LockSemaphore      = 0x0
SpinCount          = 0x00000000
```

Comment: Can you give the output for the command(!cs 00365db0 00d7f6d8 00365d68). One of them would be the critical section mostly 00365db0 this looks cs. This would give who is holding this critical section or this is first thread who is trying to accuir this( !cs 00365db0)

Comment: @tmp, thanks for the quick reply. The result is big. Shall I add it to the question?

Comment: added result of !cs 00365db0 00d7f6d8 00365d68 to the question.

Comment: Is it possible that port has been closed already? Please set a breakpoint on usbmon!DynaMon_ClosePort at the beginning of execution and check who is calling it. Another possibility is that you might simply have a heap corruption. Could you execute spoolsv.exe under full paged heap and see if it identifies any issues?

Comment: @SevaTitov, thank you for recommending the idea to debug Dynamon_ClosePort. I will also try debugging the spoolsv.exe under full paged heap. This is possible using gflags right?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that your critical section is already been deleted by some other thread using DeleteCriticalSection API. Due to this your current thread(where program is crashing) is trying to call EnterCriticalSection to the already deleted one or may be this critical section is not been initialized by InitializeCriticalSection From the log(!cs)

```
DebugInfo          = 0x00104290
Critical section   = 0x00365db0 (+0x365DB0)
LOCKED
LockCount          = 0x1
OwningThread       = 0x00000000
RecursionCount     = 0x0
LockSemaphore      = 0xAA8
SpinCount          = 0x00000000

WARNING: critical section DebugInfo = 0x00000000 doesn't point back
to the DebugInfo found in the active critical sections list = 0x00104290.
The critical section was probably reused without calling DeleteCriticalSection
```

Comment: thanks for analysis. Yes, the CS at 0x365DB0 is NULL when I use dd 0x365DB0. It is a call from MS dlls. I cannot understand how and why this could be NULL as our code does not have access to that CS. We are only passing hPort. What can cause the internal CS to become NULL?

Comment: Based on your call stack it looks like "usbmon" dll owns this particular cs. usbmon!CBasePort::open() normally indicates that there might be some method provided by "usbmon" like CBasePort::init() which might be initializing this particular cs. It might be the case that your thread might not have called the CBasePort::init() equivalent method. This might be scenario. This is just my guess as I do not have any idea about these modules logic. Hope it helps and good luck!!!
'

Comment: Thank you. CBasePort::init() is not available but I will look into that way if we have any such init functions. Can you please explain me how you gave start and end address for !cs command?